# UIWebView within UITableView to slow

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I got  `UITableView` with e.g. 5 sections . the headerViews of each section are `UIWebViews` (to display html formatted Text).

While scrolling to a section header which wasn't in window before. the html content is empty until the scroll animation is stopped. after stopping the `UIWebView` loads its content.

is it possible to view the text while scrolling like a label?

Comment: piece of your code may help to figure out the issue...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coretext` for this purpose. Its simply awesome just as using a `UILabel`.

Answer (score 0):

You should read this article: http://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/fast-uitableviewcell-with-a-uiwebview/

It explains your problem very well and also comes with some code that will help you!

[edit]Also [this one](http://gavrix.wordpress.com/2011/04/28/uiwebview-inside-uitableviewcell/), with a [github demo here](https://github.com/gavrix/UISynchedWebView-demo)